# An alternative to Android's webview

Tags: android, android-webview

Does anyone knows an alternative to Android's webview component ? For some reasons, it's functionality's are insufficient for me : I need to be able to catch every single request to some url, when i'm browsing a wml page (wap). Anyway, I need to be able to do stuff that Android's webview is not made for.
I thought "hey, let's play with the source code, I'm pretty sure that webviews are using apache.org librairies to access internet".
Oh boy was I mistaken. Webviews use native code, and that's where I'm stuck.

So I was wondering if anyone knew of another web browser view, in pure java, that would be open source and nice. It's not a problem if it's slow, i'm displaying some basic wap pages...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've been looking for something similar.. Have you found any good approaches so far? One thing I could find is that, we could use loadData method in WebViewClient to fetch HTML and then use webview to render that. Still resources are a problem.

Comment: Well. I'm now fetching all data with HttpRequest I do on my own. I then parse the data I get. If it's regular HTML, I use the webview to render it. If it's not, I'm converting it to basic HTML, then render it using the webview. I inject javascript so that each time a link is clicked, i can intercept the event, and do the process all over again. It's pretty heavy and ugly, but works.
As you can see, it's not a pretty, easy to put together solution...

Comment: True. Its lot of custom code to get the stuff working. I'm also looking at getting firefox android version (fennec) to be embedded in my app. There I should be able to override the network layer alone. Not much progress yet, though.

Comment: But then your app will grow accordingly... That can be a problem as well !

Comment: that's true. Any chance you could share that code you've written.. or any pointers to your implementation..

Comment: Well, sharing I cannot, as it probably belongs to my company, but a few pointers : I have an activity that i called WebViewActivity. It's content view is of course a webview. When I wan't to display a URI, I first load it with a HttpRequest (an HttpPost if it has post data). I then check the request result to see if it's HTML. If it is, I load id using webview.loadData(...). If not, I parse it using the JDOM api. I recreate and HTML document with JDOM. And render the result with webview.loadData(...). While converting, if there is a link, I replace it with a "onclick" attribute.

Comment: The onclick calls a javascript function, passing it the URL of the link. I add to the webview an JavaScriptInterface, with the webview.addJavascriptInterface(...) method. This object has a method that is called when "onclick" is triggered. And this method, basically, does it all over again. Download stuff, check if it's html, and if not converts it... Heavy, isn't it ?

Comment: yeah.. quite heavy. Wanted to avoid html parsing, still trying..

Comment: If you come up with something better, let me know !

Comment: Hope there's an answer sometime. The WebView has awful performance, but there are many browser apps--it would be nice if Dolphin or Opera or someone would make a library for a lightweight WebView alternative that could be included in an app. Yes, it would increase the size of the app, but would offer much better performance and still allow the developer to retain control of the application flow (as opposed to sending an intent to an external browser)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extend WebView's functionality by using setWebViewClient & setWebChromeClient.

```
WebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
WebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {..}
```

You can handle each and every request sent/received from the WebView by overriding the below methods:

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {..}
public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {..}
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {..}
```

Comment: I did. The trouble is that the behavior of web views are inconsistent between mobile phones. It's a pain, really.

Comment: I'll mark it as answer, because I ended up using classic web view and stuff. I still had to parse all the code, and rewrite html from wml... It was a pain.

Comment: Not to mention, that requests for audio/video never reach these methods.

Answer (score 3):

The crosswalk project: https://crosswalk-project.org/ might be what you need.  But beware, there are places where it differs from the stock webview.  In some ways better, in some ways worse.  For example, it supports WebGL (good), but currently the background cannot be transparent (bad).  The really good news, it seems to be very actively supported, running it's own Jira to track and fix and Intel seems to be very involved.

Comment: An interesting approach of course, but it will really add a lot of weight to an application. Still, it's probably the best solution for a web view consistant across several versions of Android.

Answer (score -2):

Try to see how was Opera Mini programmed.

But I think you must program it if you want another one . But i would be surprised if it has a nice performance.

Answer (score -7):

```
       Try this: 

      goButton4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View view) {               
               Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://tory.com/");
               Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
               startActivity(intent);                  
        }
    });
```

Comment: Well, that's just gonna open the browser and that absolutely not what I'm looking for... thanks though.

Comment: Read and then answer!